# Replacing labels in dataframe while plotting

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, csv, dataframe

My dat.csv is as follows:

```
State, Pop
AP,100
UP,200
TN,90
```

I want to plot it and so my code is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.read_csv('dat.csv')

df.plot(kind='bar').set_xticklabels(df.State)
plt.show()
```

However, I want to replace the labels which are in another csv file,

```
labels.csv

Column,Name,Level,Rename
State,AP,AP,Andhra Pradesh
State,TN,TN,Tamil Nadu
State,UP,UP,Uttar Pradesh
```

Is it possible for me to replace the labels in the plot with the labels in my labels.csv file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `merge` + `set_index`

```
df=df.merge(labels,left_on='State',right_on='Name',how='left')
df
Out[1094]: 
  State   Pop Column Name Level          Rename
0    AP   100  State   AP    AP  Andhra Pradesh
1    UP   200  State   UP    UP   Uttar Pradesh
2    TN    90  State   TN    TN      Tamil Nadu



df.set_index('Rename')['Pop'].plot(kind='Bar')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. is there a simpler way to limit the columns?

Comment: @EchchamaNayak what you mean limit the column, you want to drop the column ? `df.merge(labels[['Name','Rename']],left_on='State',right_on='Name',how='left')`

Comment: oh i understand. Thank you so much

Comment: @EchchamaNayak type df.columns , there should be a blank then change 'Pop' to ' Pop'